# glNormalPointer define an array of vertex or faces normals?

Tags: opengl, normals

I use `glNormalPointer()` to load values of normals in  my code. The problem is that I could not understand which normals should I load per vertex or per face? Interestingly, but I try both variants and could not see any differences.

**Could You clarify which normals should I pass to shader?**

I use normals in the following vertex shader:

```
#version 120

void main() {
    vec3 normal, lightDir;
    vec4 diffuse, ambient, globalAmbient;
    float NdotL;

    normal = gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix *  gl_Vertex;
    // Calculate color
    lightDir = normalize(vec3(gl_LightSource[0].position));
    NdotL = max(abs(dot(normal, lightDir)), 0.0);
    diffuse = gl_Color * gl_LightSource[0].diffuse;
    ambient = gl_Color * gl_LightSource[0].ambient;
    globalAmbient = gl_LightModel.ambient * gl_Color;
    gl_FrontColor =  NdotL * diffuse + globalAmbient + ambient;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All vertex attribute arrays, whether built-in or user-defined, provide data for each vertex, with a 1:1 ratio between vertex shader invocations and elements fetched from the array. OpenGL has no concept of "face normals". You can use [flat interpolation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interpolation_qualifier) and [knowledge of the provoking vertex](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Provoking_vertex) to create the effect of face normals, but your input data will still have to have a normal for each vertex.